# How to pass workflow parameter to job

Tags: docker, circleci

I am using circle ci to build couple of docker images. The docker image rely on `-build-arg my_var=val`. I have modified my circleci job to handle this arg i.e.,

```
  build_image:
    docker: 
      - image: google/cloud-sdk:latestare run
    steps:
      - run: docker build --build-arg my_var=${my_var} -t .
```

Now the problem is that how would i pass `my_var` from `workflow` to the job. I used `command` but i think its illegal there.

```
workflows:
  version: 2

  build-image-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      -  build_image:
          command: |
            echo "export my_var=val" >> $BASH_ENV
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a parameter to the build_image job

```
build_image:
  parameters:
    my_var:
      type:string
  docker: 
    - image: google/cloud-sdk:latestare run
  steps:
    - run: docker build --build-arg my_var=<< parameters.my_var >> -t .

workflows:
  version: 2

  build-image-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build_image:
          my_var: some_value
```